# Comparing a value in between with a values of a column

Tags: excel

[image]

My excel have 2 sheet. First sheet contains a Target column. There is a Point Column as well. I want if the target value in between sheet2 then corresponding point of sheet2 is plased in the Point column of sheet1. I try using vlookup but its works only the value of sheet2 is exactly same, not in the range. Any help will be appricite.

Comment: I need a formula in Point(sheet1) to find the point from sheet2

Comment: Sheet1 Point column is D

Comment: Target value of sheet1 need to compare with sheet 2 (A&B) and return corresponding point value to sheet1 point

Comment: Return sheet2 point value to sheet1 point value depending on the target range of sheet1

Answer (score 1):

Note that the sheet should give point `n` if it is between `(n-1)*100000+1` and `n*100000`.

So just take `D5 = ROUNDUP(B5/100000, 0)` and it will work, in this specific case.

It is also likely to be much faster than using `VLOOKUP`.